# SelectField : why returning "Not a valid choice error"?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm pretty noob in python, so it's probably a stupid question, sorry for that.

contact.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="POST" action="/">
    
       <fieldset class="form-field">
        {{ form.iro.label }}<br>
        {{ form.iro }}
        {% if form.iro.errors %}
          <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in form.iro.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </fieldset><br>
      
      {{ form.sub_issue }}

      </form>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextField, SubmitField, FieldList, FormField, SelectField, Form
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Optional


class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    """Contact form."""
    iro = SelectField(
        'IRO',
        choices=[]
    )
    
    sub_issue = SubmitField('Open an issue')
```

in my code, I populate the choices argument of SelectField with a json from a request

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
      r = requests.get("https://...",verify=False)
      form.iro.choices= [(iro,iro) for iro in list(r.json().values())]
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      if form.validate_on_submit():
      #code when submitted...
```

But when I click on the submit button, a "Not a valid choice" error appears under my SelectField

Do you know why ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see values in variables in `contact()` and maybe you will see if it gets correct value in `SelectField`. And if it gets wrong values then maybe it helps you fix it.

Comment: in `GET` you add values to `choices` but you don't have these values in `choices` when you run `else:` and check `validate_on_submit():` - so it can't check if you selected correct value and it sends `"Not a valid choice"`. You have to add them to `choices` in both situations - in `GET` and in `POST`. Maybe after getting from http://...` keep them in global variable and add them to `choices` again in `else` before you check `validate_on_submit():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but for me all problem is that you add values to `choices` only in `GET`. And when you run `validate_on_submit():` for `POST` then `choices` is empty and it will always give "Not a valid choice"

You would need something like this.

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    r = requests.get("https://...", verify=False)
    form.iro.choices = [(iro,iro) for iro in list(r.json().values())]

    if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      if form.validate_on_submit():
      #code when submitted...
```

If `requests` always get the same values then you should read them only once at start (outside `contact()`), write in local file or database and read them in `contact()`

If `requests` may gives different values then you should read them in `GET`, save in file with uniqe name (or in database with uniqe ID) and send this name/ID to `HTML` as hidden field. And later in `POST` you should use this unique name/ID to read from file/database.

More or less

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'GET':

      r = requests.get("https://...", verify=False)
      form.iro.choices = [(iro,iro) for iro in list(r.json().values())]

      save r.json() in unique file

      form.hidden_field = unique_file

      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:

      unique_file = form.hidden_field

      read r.json() from unique file

      form.iro.choices = [(iro,iro) for iro in list(r.json().values())]

      if form.validate_on_submit():
      #code when submitted...
```

Comment: Oh thanks ! I try this solution and it's working. Pretty strange logic, but your solution is nice, thank you.